# jQuery.parseJSON not work

Tags: php, jquery, post

For get multiple variable from php , i use this code :

go.php :

```
if(isset($_POST['check'])){
    $x['contact']=0;
    $x['ticket']=0;
    echo json_encode($x);
}
```

and script code is :

```
$.post('go.php', {check:check}, function(data){
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            $('#contact_count').html(response.contact);
            $('#ticket_count').html(response.ticket);
        });
```

but not work and error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contact' of null

Comment: Can you add the output if your php? My hunch is it isn't valid json.

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(data)`

Comment: or `console.log(response)`

Comment: error of console : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contact' of null (index):17
(anonymous function) (index):17
k jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
l.fireWith jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
y jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
d

Comment: You already posted that error in the question. What is the output of `console.log(data)`? We don't need to see `console.log(response)`, the error message implies that `response = null`.

Comment: i found only this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contact' of null

Comment: This cannot be the error when logging the `data` variable. Just post the output of `console.log(data)`

Comment: right click > inspect emelent > console tab , i found error here

Comment: The error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contact' of null ` only occurs if you try to access the property contact. Can you please look up the response for your request in the [network tab](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/chrome-dev-tools-networking-and-the-console/)?

Comment: @Mohammad You can see all your requests in the network tab instead of console tab. There should be a request to `go.php`, you can look into what the request has sent and what it got back as response.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told  ajax the type of data it is returning

```
dataType:'json'
```

Use this fashion

```
 $.ajax({
type : "POST",
url : ajax_url ,
dataType:'json',........
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this:

```
$.post('go.php', {check:check}, function(data){
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(response); //You can see the value in the Browser Console
            $('#contact_count').html(response.contact);
            $('#ticket_count').html(response.ticket);
        });
```

And can you look what the Object contains.

Comment: error of console : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contact' of null (index):17
(anonymous function) (index):17
k jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
l.fireWith jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
y jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
d

Comment: Then just give me the String in data `alert(data);`

Comment: i found only this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contact' of null

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the data type `json` as last parameter and it will be automatically parsed as JSON:

```
$.post('go.php', {check:check}, function(response) {
  $('#contact_count').html(response.contact);
  $('#ticket_count').html(response.ticket);
}, 'json');
```